# Responsive webdesign: Media query doesn't trigger when tilting tablet back

Tags: responsive-design, media

I am having the following issue:

1. When I load my page in **portrait** view on my device it triggers the portrait media query - **CORRECT**
2. When I tilt the device to **landscape** it triggers the landscape media query - **CORRECT**
3. When I tilt the device **back to portrait** it still triggers the landscape media query - **NOT CORRECT**

My media queries look like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    body, a, p, label, input, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, table, tr, td, div, textarea, button, span {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media only screen {
    body, a, p, label, input, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, table, tr, td, div, textarea, button, span {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fugured out what the problem was. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 as the test device and it must have an issue when tilting the device. I tried it on my Galaxy S2 and it worked fine